# Trying to learn XQuery with HTML

Tags: html, xquery

I'm trying to figure out if XQuery is a good solution for a project I'm working on. I haven't really worked with it before and I'm trying to follow simple tutorials. I'm trying this one here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_add.asp

Seems pretty straight forward but based on the impression I'm getting from it I can't get it to work. What this is saying to me is that I have to create a an HTML document containing this:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Bookstore</h1>

<ul>
{
for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
order by $x/title
return <li>{data($x/title)}. Category: {data($x/@category)}</li>
}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And this queries the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

It seems that this isn't as simple since the data is interpreted by the browser as syntactically incorrect HTML. I tried adding the HTML code to the XML file but again, it shows incorrect XML formatting. Are you supposed to use this as an XSLT file instead of HTML? It may be a stupid question but I'm not finding a straight forward answer to the question "What do you need to run XQuery in an HTML page?" Why wouldn't this tutorial not clarify that you need third party libraries or API's or something else. Am I not referencing the xml file properly? Or I am just being stupid (that could be a possibility)?

Comment: You need an XQuery processor on the server side.

Comment: See Erics answer. If you want to use XQuery in a HTML context you might want to take a look at RESTXQ (see http://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ for some examples/use cases). Why the tutorial isn't clarifying stuff we can't really say, but take at http://www.w3fools.com/ and you might get an idea why.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes to this dirkk. I didn't realize that about w3schools. They have been helpful in some ways in the past but I had no idea they weren't that committed to having factual and updated content. Thanks, that answered my question. I will look into Xquery engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQuery is (as Eric Bloch has said) usually run on the server.

If you want to run XQuery in the browser, you should look at http://www.xqib.org/ -- it uses the [Micro XQuery](http://mxquery.org/) engine, which is written in Java and cross-compiled to Javascript.